# How can I use defmacro in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I use defmacro in Javascript?

```
defmacro ()?
```

Or, some other formats?

Comment: There is [`new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), the slightly less evil brother of [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just cannot.
Javascript is not Lisp